# Querying users by meta value and getting a strange answer

Tags: query, user-meta

Here is my case:

I am trying to get all users with some value related to a specific meta key. In other words, I don't want to select users that have nothing on that meta key (mps_finalDate).

So here is my code:

```
$users = get_users(array(
 'meta_key'     => 'mps_finalDate',
 'meta_value'   => '',
 'meta_compare' => '!=',
 ));
```

Which works the same as

```
$users = get_users(array(
  'meta_key'     => 'mps_finalDate',
  ));
```

But the problem is: this code is selecting users that once had some value on this meta field, even if now they have nothing on it. It seems that the `update_user_meta( $user_id, 'mps_finalDate', trim( $_POST['mps_finalDate'] ) );` I am using in my code is not deleting the previous value on the db, thus causing this issue.

In conclusion: the above code is not selecting a user that never had a value on the meta key field `mps_finalDate`(which is desired), but it is selecting a user that once had a value on it, even if now this value is `""`.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using a custom meta field but searching default meta attributes.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query

WP_User_Query might be a more robust solution.

So it would look like something like :

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'mps_finaldate',
                'value'   => '',
                'compare' => '!='
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'mps_finaldate',
                'value'   => null,

                'compare' => '!='
            )
        )
    )
 );
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

EDIT:

`WP_User_Query` is a wrapper for the `get_users` function you were using *but it, as a wrapper, also is going to do the work of the `get_userdata` function*

This is great and detrimental for 2 reasons (each)

Great: it can be hooked (someone edit me)
Great: code longevity is sustained because it is core api use

Detrimental: anyone and everyone's plugins can also hook 
Detrimental: anyone and everyone's plugins can also hook

I'd go the route of using the `wp_user_query` class if only because the arguments are structured and documented well (but I'll stay for the longevity benefit of the approach being wp_core api)

your mileage may vary

Comment: Well, your code worked for me. I don't know why mine didn't (isn't `get_users()` a `Wrapper for WP_User_Query`)? Anyway, I will stick with yours. Thanks a lot!

Comment: U have it backwards. `wp_user_query` is a wrapper for get_users. You can accomplish the Sam thing with get_users but you would need to run the results through get_usermetadata as well in order to compare custom field data. Also - notice the AND clause that was originally omitted. A 0 length string is not the samething as a null

Comment: here's the real rub - `get_users` is also "probably" more efficient, because the `wp_user_query` can be hooked and filtered - yes : the best and worst of WP authoring. if you wish to be a purist - push the `get_users` results through `get_userdata` but expect ONLY your explicit opinions on the matter - link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata

edit: also - very welcome! im happy it worked for you:D

Comment: This is confusing... From the Codex, about `get_users`: `Wrapper for WP_User_Query. Retrieves an array of users matching the criteria given in $args.`. If one can be hooked and filtered, the other too, isn't?

Comment: @LuisRock - I'm sorry you are correct regarding the vocabulary, my apologies. `WP_User_Query` makes use of both `get_users` and `get_userdata` - the later is required in order to pass / run queries structured around  **custom** meta values. `get_users` will only look at core meta fields